# how i can write a function in node js (get) and send data

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

how we can write the same function in nodejs

```
 <?php

       $_ack = $_GET["ack"];


       if ( $_ack == "true" ) {
         echo "{";
         echo "\"". $_id ."\" : { \"downlinkData\" : \"0102030405060708\" }";
         echo "}";
       } 
       header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
       header("Content-Type : application/json");
    ?>
```

this is my example is it correct :........................................................................................................................................

```
 function( ){   
        var id = req.param("refID")
        var message =  {      id : { downlinkData : "0102030405060708" } }
        res.send(200);
        if(id== "true") 
        res.end( JSON.stringify(message) ); 



  }
```

Comment: res.send(200) will send the string "200" - so, no, your code is not correct, you're also not setting the content type - see the example on the nodejs for a simplified example of setting the response headers ... it's right there on the front page

Comment: thanks , what is the equivalence of "echo" in nodejs

Comment: I was wrong about res.send - that is invalid in the standard http module ... here's the documentation for http module - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send out a header with Node.js:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

And generally, with PHP if you're going to output JSON don't hardcode it like that... PHP has [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) that will do it for you.